# Reading and parsing a XBRL file in Perl (or converting into normal XML / JSON!)

Tags: perl, xbrl

I'm drawing a blank on this. XBRL seems to be based on XML - yet there seems to be no agreed structure for it. I'm taking data from http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html , and I want to parse the file into usable data

How are you supposed to process XBRL files and output usable data structures? For instance, I want to see what the gross turnover was for last years return.

This must be possible, otherwise what is the point in Company House providing the data?

Any gudance is much appreciated! I feel like I'm going round and round in circles with this one

Comment: There seems to be e.g. [XBRL::JPFR](http://p3rl.org/XBRL::JPFR) on CPAN which could help.

Comment: @choroba thanks. Am I missing something though? The documentation seems scarce at the least. Also, that only seems to be for "Japan Financial Reporting"?

Comment: If you look at the source for that module it's using `XML::LibXML` internally.

Comment: @AKHolland thanks - not sure how to use that though? It doesn't seem to be a "proper" XML file as such - so guess you have to muck about with it? An example file Companies House provide: https://pastebin.com/QTZ2YMJp

Comment: Re "*yet there seems to be no agreed structure for it*", The schema used is found [here](http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd). ....hmmm, the document you placed in pastebin doesn't have an instance of `{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl`, but I think you can treat the `{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}body` element has having the same schema as `{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl`, except also permitting extra elements (from other namespaces).

Comment: hmmm, why does the "Sample of XBRL" on the page you linked show a proper XBRL document while the sample you linked doesn't?

Comment: @ikegami thanks. The page suggests they offer 2 types. One is an actual .xml file, whereas the other is iXBRL (which has inline + html). The issue is how to extract the data into usable numbers / columns. I'll have another play with it next week and see if I can come up with a usable system to extract it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XBRL follows the [XBRL specifications](https://specifications.xbrl.org), which are built on XML.  Companies House uses the [Inline XBRL (iXBRL)](https://specifications.xbrl.org/work-product-index-inline-xbrl-inline-xbrl-1.1.html) variant of XBRL in which the XBRL tags are embedded in an HTML document.

It's not accurate to say that the documents don't follow any defined structure; they follow the above specifications and are validated as doing so upon receipt by Companies House.

However, the iXBRL reports collected by Companies House are financial reports, which follow applicable accounting standard and the accounting standards permit quite a lot of variation in exactly what is reported by each company.

Data in XBRL is tagged by associating a value (e.g. 1,000) with a concept (e.g. "Revenue") and some dimensions (such as period and units).

The accounting terms (such as "Assets", "Revenue", etc) are defined as concepts in a taxonomy.  Because of the variation permitted by the accounting standards, you may find that not all companies disclose the concepts that you are looking for.

In the case of Companies House data, this is further complicated by the fact that many smaller companies can and do file abbreviated accounts which don't include the Profit and Loss statement, so "turnover" often simply isn't reported.  The filing of iXBRL to Companies House is optional, and many companies choose to make their data less accessible by filing on paper.

In terms of making the data easier to work with, I would strongly recommend using an existing XBRL processor that will take care of reading not only the iXBRL report, but the associated taxonomy.

The most widely used open source processor is [Arelle](https://www.arelle.org), and there are also many commercial processors available too (see https://software.xbrl.org).

Arelle will allow you to work with XBRL data via a Python API, or it can be used to convert it to the new, [xBRL-JSON](https://specifications.xbrl.org/work-product-index-open-information-model-open-information-model.html) format.

Comment: Re "*Companies House uses the Inline XBRL (iXBRL) variant of XBRL in which the XBRL tags are embedded in an HTML document.*", According to the page linked by the OP, it provides both the standard and inline variants

Comment: @pdw thanks - just installing Arelle to give it a whirl. Converting to xBRL-JSON sounds promising

Comment: @pdw - hmm so I've installed the modules ( `sudo apt-get install python2.7 python2.7-lxml python2.7-tk`), and then uploaded the source code into /arelle - then tried running with:  `cd /arelle; ./arelleCmdLine --help` , but it doesn't run. What am I doing wrong? (the documentation seems a bit scarce). I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @ikegami Companies House supported XBRL before adopting iXBRL.  I'm not sure if XBRL is still accepted, but I'd expect all current filings to be iXBRL as that is the format required by HMRC for tax returns.

Comment: @AndrewNewby I use `python3 ./arelleCmdLine.py --help`.  If that doesn't work, let me know what error you're seeing.

Comment: @pdw - thanks I'm using python 2.7, so tried: ` python2 ./arelleCmdLine.py --help
`, but I get an error: https://ibb.co/z7SqhP2

Comment: @pdw ah ok I got it. Turns out I had python2.7 and 3 installed. So trying with your command told me I didn't have some bits installed. This seems to have done the trick: `apt -y install python3-pip; pip3 install --upgrade lxml; pip3 install --upgrade isodate`. Gonna give it a go now :)

Comment: @pdw ah ok - so I'm testing: `python3 ./arelleCmdLine.py -f "/home/xxxx/ch-accounts/Prod224_0067_00908825_20190624.html"` , and it stays running for a while - but then justoutputs:  `[info] loaded in 12.11 secs at 2020-07-27T07:21:51 - /home/xxxx/ch-accounts/Prod224_0067_00908825_20190624.html` .. how do I get the output?

Comment: @pdw wahoo - I think I've got it to work. `python3 ./arelleCmdLine.py --facts "/home/output/test.json" -f "/home/xxx/Prod224_0067_07873760_20171231.html"`. I still need to test and make sure the data outputted is the same across the files (i.e I have access to gross turnover etc), but it looks good so far. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewNewby Glad you got it working.  The "--facts" option actually gives you an older, Arelle-specific JSON format.  If you actually want xBRL-JSON, use: `--plugins saveLoadableOIM --saveLoadableOIM foo.json`

Comment: @pdw thanks - but when I do that I get an error? `python3 /arelle/arelleCmdLine.py --plugins saveLoadableOIM --disclosureSystem="hmrc" --saveLoadableOIM "/home/xxx/foo.json" -f "/home/xxx/Prod223_2706_00126369_20200331.html"` = error: no such option: --saveLoadableOIM

Comment: Is this the latest Arelle from github?  Does the file Arelle/arelle/plugin/saveLoadableOIM.py exist?  If you run just `python3 /arelle/arelleCmdLine.py --plugins savelLoadableOIM` do you get a message about the plugin being activated?  If you stick `--help` on the end does `saveLoadableOIM` appear in the docs?  It might be worth starting a fresh question about Arelle + xBRL-JSON as I think this may be useful to others.

Comment: @pdw sorry for the late reply. Not sure how I missed this one! This is what I get with that command: https://ibb.co/QKvQWfb . `python3 /arelle/arelleCmdLine.py --help | grep saveLoadableOIM` gives me no result, so I guess its not.  Version wise I get: `
Arelle(r) 1.2018.01.06 (64bit)`

Comment: @pdw ah ok I got it. For some reason I was on a really old version! I've updated it to 2020 a version and it now has that plugin! I'm getting an error running it on an XML file, so will start a new post as suggested